# Toggle width with jQuery

Tags: jquery

How do I toggle the width of a div with animation?  My goal is to change the width when I click on the blue div.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#toggle-button').click(function() {
    $('#toggle').toggle(function() {
      $('#toggle').animate({
        width: "200px"
      });
    }, function() {
      $('#toggle').animate({
        width: "300px"
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#toggle {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
}

#toggle-button {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="toggle-button"></div>
<div id="toggle"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you Rory McCrossan and lonesomeday

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The issue with your code is due to the use of the (now deprecated) [`toggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) event handler. You can implement the logic yourself using `click()`, though:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#toggle-button').click(function() {
    var toggleWidth = $("#toggle").width() == 300 ? "200px" : "300px";
    $('#toggle').animate({ width: toggleWidth });
  });
});
```

```css
#toggle {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
}

#toggle-button {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="toggle-button"></div>
<div id="toggle"></div>
```

---

**- 2022 Update -**

The better approach would now be to toggle the class on successive clicks, using `toggleClass()`, and use CSS `transition` to animate the width:

```js
jQuery($ => {
 $('#toggle-button').on('click', e => {
  $('#toggle').toggleClass('foo');
 });
});
```

```css
#toggle {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  transition: width 0.3s;
}

#toggle.foo {
  width: 300px;
}

#toggle-button {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="toggle-button"></div>
<div id="toggle"></div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do in DEMO?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you share an example with  border toggle ?

Comment: Nice solution, wondering why it doesn't work with width in %.

Comment: @eye-wonder note that it will only work with very old versions of jQuery (ie. 1.7.2 as in your fiddle) as the behaviour of the `toggle()` method was changed. Your example doesn't work in the latest jQuery (3.2.1): http://jsfiddle.net/ZfHZV/1749/

Comment: For percentage width see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781620/toggle-width-with-jquery/45566713#45566713

Answer (score 9):

Dude! your code works, you just don't understand what it does...

```
  $('#toggle-button').click( function() { // Execute when the toggle button is clicked.
    $('#toggle').toggle(function() {      // Attach toggle function that fire different
                                          // callback when clicked.
      $('#toggle').animate({width:"200px"});
    }, function() {
      $('#toggle').animate({width:"300px"});
    });
  });
```

Click on the blue div and then on the red div couple of time and see how it works.

Note that you better attach the toggle click callbacks with `one` instead of `click` to avoid multiple callback of clicks:

```
  $('#toggle-button').one('click', function() {
    $('#toggle').toggle(function() {
        $('#toggle').animate({width:"200px"});
    }, function() {
        $('#toggle').animate({width:"300px"});
    });
  });
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZfHZV/9/)

Comment: When you say it works, you mean "it does something". I don't think it does what it is *intended* to do...

Comment: @lonesomeday. He didn't mention what he's trying to do... it toggles the div, so it works. I added an explanations to what his code does and how to use it. I can't do a lot more with that question... :(

Comment: I was a little unclear about my intensions, sorry about that, @gdoron

Answer (score 3):

There are two jQuery methods called `toggle`. One toggles visibility, which isn't relevant here. The other applies a click handler, which fires functions alternately. This is what you are using. However, you're using it wrong.

What you're actually doing is waiting for `#toggle-button` to be clicked, then you bind a click handler to `#toggle`. So the animation would occur whenever `#toggle` was clicked after the first time `#toggle-button` was clicked. (The situation would get more complicated after multiple clicks on `#toggle-button`.

You want to use `toggle` directly on `#toggle-button`:

```
$('#toggle-button').toggle(function() { //fired the first time
  $('#toggle').animate({width:"200px"});
}, function() { // fired the second time 
  $('#toggle').animate({width:"300px"});
});
```

[Working code](http://jsfiddle.net/ZfHZV/5/) (nb that since you start at 200px, the first click appears to do nothing)

Comment: This works on jfiddle but does not work on my web page. I copied the code exactly but I cannot get it to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Note that this logic will only work with very old versions of jQuery (ie. <1.9). The `toggle()` method behaviour has since been changed: http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Answer (score 1):

Try This:
It Work on All versions of Jquery || jquery 1.10.1 ||  to || jquery 2.1.4 ||

Script

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
            $(document).ready( function(){
            $('#toggle-button').click( function() {
            var toggleWidth = $("#toggle").width() == 800 ? "0px" : "800px";
            $('#toggle').animate({ width: toggleWidth });
            });
            });
    </script>
```

```js
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('#toggle-button').click( function() {
        var toggleWidth = $("#toggle").width() == 800 ? "0px" : "800px";
        $('#toggle').animate({ width: toggleWidth });
    });
});
```

```css
#toggle{
    height:200px;
    width:0px;
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Toggle Width with jQuery</h1>
<input id="toggle-button" type="button" value="Click me!"/>
<div id="toggle"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using JQuery 2.1.1 and setting width and transition with CSS. Also works with percentage width, color change, etc.

```js
$('#button-enlarge').on('click', function () {
  $('.box').toggleClass('expanded');
});
```

```css
.box.expanded {
  background-color: #e99;
  transition: all .3s;
  width: 100%;
}
.box {
  width: 40%;
  transition: all .3s;
  background-color: #f00;
  color: #fff;
  height: 140px;
}
#button-enlarge { 
 padding: 10px 15px;
 border: 1px solid #999;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button-enlarge">Click here</div>
<div class="box">box</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Type Coercion Warning

Using `$("#toggle").width() == 800` can result in unexpected type coercion.

Instead, consider using the following:

```
var foo = $("#toggle").width();
var bar = foo === 0 ? "100%" : "0";
```

**Note** the type and value comparison operator `===` comparing the value of `input.width()` to the numerical primitive `0`. As `input.width()` evaluates to a value of the primitive type *number*, when it is equal to `0` this condition will return `true`.

The practice of using a value comparison operator `==` side-steps the JavaScript type system, which has the potential to lead to unexpected bugs. Although it is less dangerous within a conditional statement, there is still a risk of unexpected behavior. Please see [this article for more information on type coercion](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/js-type-coercion-explained-27ba3d9a2839).

Answer (score -1):

`$('#toggle-button').one('click', function() {
$('#toggle').animate({ width: 'toggle'}, 1000);
});`

this toggle 0 to your defined width

i tried this and work

```
$("#searchIcon").click(function(){
var toggleWidth = "0px";
if($("#searchbox").width() == 118)
{
    toggleWidth="0px";
}
else
{
    toggleWidth="120px";
}
$('#searchbox').animate({ width: toggleWidth });
```

});