# Jquery toggle animated width.

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need my Jquery code to animate `summary_box` div as so it slides the following way.

On load it will be on on browser window and when `summary_button2` div is clicked it will slide(change width to 0) to the right and despair and appear again once the button is clicked again.
What I have sort of works, but I'm not sure what this is doing: `(== 300 ? "0" : "300px";)`???

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('#summary_button2').click( function() {
        var toggleWidth = $("#summary_box").width() == 300 ? "0" : "300px";
        $('#summary_box').animate({ width: toggleWidth });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: ternary operator, could be: `$("#summary_box").width() == 300 ? 0 : 300;`

Comment: Looks like a synthesized conditional statement, if width of this is 300, make it 0, else make it 300. But I've never seen that in query before, I'm no js veteran though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is ternary operation - equivalent to this -

```
var toggleWidth;
if ($("#summary_box").width() == 300) {
    toggleWidth = "0";
} else {
    toggleWidth "300px";
}
```

[MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui he is answering OP's question, thats all

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui  .. that is just an equivalent code to what op is trying to understand..

Comment: in line: if ($("#summary_box").width() == 300) { //what does 300 mean? width? why no "px"?

Comment: @irm Yes 300 is width.... because .width() return's width as an integer  API  `-->` http://api.jquery.com/width/

Comment: Oh, It makes sense now. Thank you!

Comment: If I wanted to have the width as 25% of browser window instead of 300 how could I accomplish that?

Comment: @irm `$(window).width() / 4`  instead of 300

Comment: Should be toggleWidth = "300px";

Answer (score 4):

It's a ternary operator, and it's basically just a shortened if / else statement that does :

```
if ( $("#summary_box").width() == 300 ) {
   var toggleWidth = '0';
}else{
   var toggleWidth = '300px';
}
```

As a sidenote, jQuery's `animate()` has a toggle option that would do the same thing:

```
$('#summary_box').animate({ width: 'toggle'}, 1000);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vxm9R/)

Answer (score 2):

This piece of code reads like the following:

```
$("#summary_box").width() == 300 ? "0" : "300px";
```

If width() is equal to 300, return 0, else return "300px".

See [Ternary Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781620/toggle-width-with-jquery) question on StackOverflow out.

Gives a similar solution to your's try.

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mareebsiddiqui/ZfHZV/376/) fiddle as well.

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('#toggle-button').click( function() {
        var toggleWidth = $("#toggle").width() == 300 ? "0" : "300px";
        $('#toggle').animate({ width: toggleWidth });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, and works fine

```
$("#searchIcon").click(function(){
    var toggleWidth = "0px";
    if($("#searchbox").width() == 118)
    {
        toggleWidth="0px";
    }
    else
    {
        toggleWidth="120px";
    }
    $('#searchbox').animate({ width: toggleWidth });
});
```