# Change Div width again when click

Tags: jquery, css

i have one fixed header and one hidden vertical menu.

When someone click at a button, the menu appears, and the fixed header width changes from 100% to 82%.

But when i close the menu, my header dont change the value to 100% again, how can i change the width value when the button is clicked again?

CSS

```
#header{
position: fixed;
height: 36px;
width: 100%;
background-color: white;
display:inline;
z-index: 1;
}
```

JQuery

```
<script>
$(window).load(function() {

$("#hide").click(function(){

   $("#menu").fadeToggle();
   $("#header").css({"width":"82%","left":"18%"});


});
});
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: please add your codes on jsfiddle that we can modify that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Toggle width with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781620/toggle-width-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#hide").click(function(){

  $("#menu").fadeToggle();
  $('#header').toggle(function () {
    $("#header").css({"width":"82%","left":"18%"});
  }, function () {
    $("#header").css({"width":"100%","left":"18%"});
  });

});
```

If you are using jQuery 2.*, you can do this:

```
$("#hide").click(function(){

  $("#menu").fadeToggle();
  $('#header').toggleClass("active");

});
```

Just make sure `.active` is something like this:

```
.active{
  width:82%;
  left:18%;
}
```

Comment: Note that `.toggle()` event has been removed since version 1.9

Comment: Thanks @Felix, added another option if they are using 2.*