# expandable fixed div on right of browser window

Tags: jquery, html, css

Below I have the code for my div which is fixed to the right side of the page, however I am completely at a loss as to how to make it expandable so when its clicked it opens up to a contact form. I also want it to poke out a small amount and read Free Quote!.

html

```
<div id="slidingpanel"></div>
```

css

```
#slidingpanel {
position: fixed;
width: 30px;
height: 200px;
z-index: 1;
right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781620/toggle-width-with-jquery You can easily modify code from answer.

Answer (score -1):

Couldn't you just use `animate`?

```
 $("#slidingpanel").on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).animate({
        width: 200
    },100);
 })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8zGp9/

Comment: Hello, could you show me this in context as I have tried it with no joy :)

Comment: Click the fiddle. When you click the element it will expand.