# How to initialize jQuery slide out with href link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have zero experience in jQuery or js but I am trying to learn, so any help is much appreciated. I have a jQuery slide out (for live chat) that I would like to have slide out once a link is clicked. Ideally

```
<a href="whatever necessary">Click Here</a>
```

And this will make the chat slide out. The only code that is in the HTML is the onload

```
<body onload="initializeLiveHelp();">
```

You can see how it works [here](http://www.netatlantic.com/pricing1/pricing) Link Fixed

If you need the jQuery I can get that as well but I was not sure if that was needed or not. Thank You

Comment: The link is not working, despite that it would be better to include a full example here: see [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: link is fixed, try now

Answer (score 0):

Try it by toggling the width. So write CSS for the closed state and use this jquery snippet to open it

[Toggle width with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781620/toggle-width-with-jquery)

Add an ID to your link so

```
<a href="whatever necessary">Click Here</a>
```

becomes

```
<a href="whatever necessary" id="mylink">Click Here</a>
```

And the jquery something like this (but not exactly). Reference the SO thread for more info and check out the fiddle. Or post more HTML here and I can help further.

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('#mylink').click( function() {
        var toggleWidth = $("#toggle").width() == 300 ? "200px" : "300px";
        $('#toggle').animate({ width: toggleWidth });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello, the jQuery is already written so when you click it opens. Is there a way to toggle that jQuery opposed to adding new? Thanks @garek007

Comment: can you post the jquery?

Comment: https://www.netatlantic.com/scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js                                                  https://www.netatlantic.com/scripts/jquery.transition.min.js

Comment: @SethC.that is the plugin, what JQuery have you written to make the box slide?

Comment: Good question, The issue here is that I did not write the code for it.

Comment: Please post the rest of your HTML and I can help more.

Comment: https://www.netatlantic.com/scripts/livehelpslideout.js  This might be what you are looking for @garek007

Comment: Naw man. Sliding is really easy, but to help you I need to see your HTML

Comment: Wait, have you coded your box yet? Your CSS? The page you linked to has a slideOut, but you want to make one just like it right?

Answer (score 0):

Trigger a click when someone clicks a link:

```
$("li a").on("click", function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $(".livehelpslideout a").trigger("click");
}
```

Preventdefault() disables default behaviour when clicking on a link, otherwise browser will load another page. Your desired behaviour for that is unclear, so you'll need to think about your logic.